# @Inject on no-args public method

Tags: java, cdi

While reviewing some code I have noticed a POJO (without scope -> @Dependant) which is injected (@Inject) in another bean and that do inject a bean (a field).
But it has also an @Inject annotation on a no-args public method that does initialisations stuff. I thought injection points only happen on field, constructor and setter

```
public class MyImpl implements MyInterface {

  @Inject
  private ParamDao paramDao;

  private Map<String,List<MyRateDto>> params;


  @Inject
  public void loadRates() {
    params = paramDao....;
  }
...
}
```

To me this method (loadRates) should have been annotated as @PostConstruct. But I was wondering what happen in such case?

I guess the method is simply called after bean creation and field injection... But I have not read anything about it in the spec or elsewhere.
Is it the expected behavior?

Environment: Java 8/JavaEE 7 that targets a JBoss EAP 7.

Thanks

Comment: please add your code as an example, this will render your question more clear. Question more clear, Answer more easy

Comment: *"Is it the expected behavior?"* Yes.

Comment: Thank you @Renato. I have edited the question and added some code. Can the question be (re)opened?

Comment: @Andreas could you tell me more... Any link to the spec or something?

Comment: @BenjaminC Spec: Javadoc of [`@Inject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Inject.html): *Constructors are injected first, followed by fields, and then methods. Fields and methods in superclasses are injected before those in subclasses. Ordering of injection among fields and among methods in the same class is not specified.* --- *Injectable methods [...] accept **zero** or more dependencies as arguments.* --- No explicit description for zero arguments. It's just that `@Inject` methods are call in arbitrary order, and arguments are resolved. No argument = nothing to resolve.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas for the clarification. I have forgotten to look at the basics, ie `@Inject` Javadoc.
You could put this comment as an answer so that it can be validated?

Comment: @BenjaminC Create an answer just to say "Yes"? Nah. But if you want an answer, you can always self-answer your question. You might even get a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) for that, if you do it well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andreas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Andreas I have been steered in the right direction.

Looking at the Javadoc of `@Inject`: "*Constructors are injected first, followed by fields, and then methods. Fields and methods in superclasses are injected before those in subclasses. Ordering of injection among fields and among methods in the same class is not specified. --- Injectable methods [...] accept zero or more dependencies as arguments.*"

So, there is no explicit description for zero arguments. But it's just that `@Inject` methods are called in arbitrary order, and arguments are resolved.
*No argument = nothing to resolve.*